# THREE.OBJLoader can not display obj file?

Tags: three.js, objloader

This is my code ... and I searched a lot about it ... but I couldn't find where is the problem that nothing will show !! also there is not any errors ! I also can send you my files if u can help me ... thank you

```
    <body>
    <script src="Three.js"></script>
    <script src="DDSLoader.js"></script>
    <script src="MTLLoader.js"></script>
    <script src="OBJLoader.js"></script>


    <script>
     // Setup a new scene
     var scene = new THREE.Scene();


     // Setup the camera
    var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
    camera.position.z = 0;
    camera.position.x = 0;
    camera.position.y = 0;
     // Setup the renderer
     var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
     renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
     document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

     var onProgress = function ( xhr ) {
                        if ( xhr.lengthComputable ) {
                            var percentComplete = xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100;
                            console.log( Math.round(percentComplete, 2) + '% downloaded' );
                        }
                    };
                    var onError = function ( xhr ) { };

                    THREE.Loader.Handlers.add( /\.dds$/i, new THREE.DDSLoader() );

    var mtlLoader = new THREE.MTLLoader();
    mtlLoader.setPath( 'obj/table/' );
    mtlLoader.load( 'table.mtl', function( materials ) {
    materials.preload();
    var objLoader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
    objLoader.setMaterials( materials );
    objLoader.setPath( 'obj/table/' );
    objLoader.load( 'table.obj', function ( object ) {
                object.position.x = 0;
                object.position.y = 0;
                object.position.z = 0;
                scene.add( object );
            }, onProgress, onError );
        });



     // Render loop to rotate our sphere by a little bit each frame
     var render = function () {
         renderer.setClearColor( 0xa9db8b );
       renderer.render(scene, camera);
     };

     render();
     </script>
<canvas width="1366" height="662" style="width: 1366px; height: 662px;"></canvas>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an option: you call `render()` before your model loaded.

Try this:

```
objLoader.load( 'table.obj', function ( object ) {
                object.position.x = 0;
                object.position.y = 0;
                object.position.z = 0;
                scene.add( object );
                render();  // call it in the callback function
            }, onProgress, onError );
        });
```

Comment: I didn't call it before !

Comment: oooooooooooooooooooo ... I change it and underestaaaaaand what's your meaaan .... thank youuuuuuu it helps

Comment: but why shows it as a black thing without any texture ?

Answer (score 0):

You are placing your object at (0,0,0) and the camera at the same location.
Try this code for your camera:

```
// Place camera on x-axis
camera.position.set(10,0,0);
camera.up = new THREE.Vector3(0,0,1);
camera.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(0,0,0));
```